# Design-time binding does not work in caliburn.micro 2.0.2

Tags: caliburn.micro

I want to use design-time binding in WPF with caliburn.micro version 2.0.2.
I made simple test project and add neccessary settings for that:

```
<Window x:Class="CaliburnTest.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
          xmlns:caliburn="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
          xmlns:caliburnTest="clr-namespace:CaliburnTest"
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance caliburnTest:MainView, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        caliburn:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
<Grid>
  <TextBlock Name="Test" Width="150" Height="50"/>
```

As a result I dont see value of textblock in design-time, but I see it after app starts.
Could someone tell me what I am missing here? Maybe some additional settings?